# PyAudio package not installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio, python-packaging

Trying to install the `PyAudio` package using `pip` is showing an error, while other packages are installing normally.
I am using python 3.7. Why is this error happening?

```
C:\Users\Himanshu>pip install PyAudio
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\himanshu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Himanshu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-romfztqt\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Himanshu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bmeri0ux\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\users\himanshu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\himanshu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\users\himanshu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\himanshu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Himanshu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-romfztqt\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Himanshu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bmeri0ux\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Himanshu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-romfztqt\PyAudio\
```

Comment: _'No such file or directory error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'_

Comment: This worked for me with Python 3.8 on Kali Linux: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/974/how-to-solve-installation-error-of-pyaudio-in-ubuntu-18-04-fatal-error-portaudio-h-file-not-found

Comment: @MathiasConradt that didn't work for me (Ubuntu 20.04, Python3.8) E: Unable to locate package python-pyaudio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running python 3.6 this works, but with python 3.7 it doesn't.

PyAudio only supports up to python 3.6:

> pip will fetch and install PyAudio wheels (prepackaged binaries). Currently, there are wheels compatible with the official distributions of Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6.

The workarounds would be to use a supported version of python, or to build and install manually - if the latter, you'll need to make sure you have the correct libraries installed and configured.

I should point out that PyAudio appears to be deprecated. It hasn't received an update since March 2017. Therefore I recommend you find another package for this.

Comment: Glad to be able to help

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Comment: on first attempt it failed with connection error, but then miraculously installed successfully, thanx very much, was looking for solution several nights ))

Answer (score 0):

On my Linux Mint 20.04

My 2 line code did install to Python 3.8

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
pip3 install PyAudio
```

However, PyAudio didn't actually work for me.

It seems, Python 3.7 and above, no longer support Pyaudio