# i can't install PyAudio in my python 3.8 What should I do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyaudio

I tried a lot of things to install PyAudio on my PC for example: 
`pip istall PyAudio`
but it says:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I also tried `pipwin install PyAudio` and `pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`
but it says `PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

What should I do?

Comment: I dont think Pyaudio is compatible with Python 3.8 yet. It think its 3.7 or 3.6 and below. Again I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Could you then accept the answer if I had solved your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyaudio is not compatible with Python 3.8. 3.7 and below work with Pyaudio. For more information, visit this similar post. [PyAudio package not installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52792906/pyaudio-package-not-installing)

Answer (score 3):

Following this link https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/install+pyaudio+pip3+ubuntu ;

**For Windows:**

```
pip install pipwin
```

then

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

**For Linux (Ubuntu)**

```
sudo apt-get install libasound-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0
pip install pyaudio --user
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for Python 2.7
`sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio`

This is for Python 3x
`sudo apt-get install python3-pyaudio`

This will solve ASAP!